# Center key and value around hash rocket

Tags: regex, vim, vim-tabular

Using an vim-tabular I am attempting to format it as follows:

```
foo = {
    "iSortCol_0" => "1",
    "sSortDir_0" => "desc",
  "iSortingCols" => "1",
   "bSortable_0" => "false",
   "bSortable_1" => "true",
   "bSortable_2" => "false",
   "bSortable_3" => "true",
   "bSortable_4" => "false",
   "bSortable_5" => "true",
   "bSortable_6" => "true",
   "bSortable_7" => "true",
   "bSortable_8" => "true"
}
```

I have a list of items in a ruby hash formated randomly, eg as follows:

```
foo = {
      "iSortCol_0" => "1",
"sSortDir_0" => "desc",
    "iSortingCols" =>"1",
     "bSortable_0" =>   "false",
     "bSortable_1" => "true",
     "bSortable_2"=> "false",
     "bSortable_3"  => "true",
     "bSortable_4"   => "false",
     "bSortable_5" => "true",
     "bSortable_6" =>    "true",
     "bSortable_7" =>"true",
     "bSortable_8" => "true"
}
```

I can get it close using `Tab /=>` but it does not totally produce the desired result:

```
foo = {
      "iSortCol_0" => "1",
"sSortDir_0"       => "desc",
    "iSortingCols" => "1",
     "bSortable_0" => "false",
     "bSortable_1" => "true",
     "bSortable_2" => "false",
     "bSortable_3" => "true",
     "bSortable_4" => "false",
     "bSortable_5" => "true",
     "bSortable_6" => "true",
     "bSortable_7" => "true",
     "bSortable_8" => "true"
}
```

How do I specify how I want let side of the aligned symbol formated?  I think I need to utilize `\zs` or `\ze` but I'm having difficulty applying them for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the alignment for each section:

```
Tabularize/=>/r1l1l0
```

`r` for right, `l` for left, and `c` for center. Each is followed by the number of spaces for each section. So you split on `=>` meaning there is a section before the `=>`, the `=>` itself, and the portion of text after the `=>`.

As I am not fond of right aligning you may want to indent your code via `=i}` then do `:Tabularize/=>/`.

Comment: Why does the integer associated with the second `l` not matter (i.e. `Tabularize/=>/r1l1l1`, `Tabularize/=>/r1l1l2`, `Tabularize/=>/r1l1l213` all produce the same result)?

Comment: From the `:h tabular-walkthrough`: "The number following the letter is the
number of spaces padding to insert before the start of the next field". As this is the last field it does not mater how much space you specify as it will not be used.

Comment: Then why does it need to be specified in the first place. Can you describe the effect of the second `l<some integer>` on the statement as a whole?

Comment: I guess it may have to do with the fact that tabularize repeats the alignment flags as more fields are found. `l1` for the second field adds 1 space after the `=>`. You can play with this and change it to a 0 and see that the `=>` and the following text will be right next to each other.